# How to get user login name using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a name of an employee For eg: "XYZ". Now i want to get its login name using script.
I have tried like this:

```
$user='XYZ'
$userName=$web.EnsureUser[$user]
```

But i m getting $userName null

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnsureUser` is a method, and you are using it as an indexer. Change `$userName=$web.EnsureUser[$user]` to `$userName=$web.EnsureUser($user)`

Answer (score 0):

To get user login user below given command

```
$user='XYZ'
$userName=$web.EnsureUser($user).UserLogin
```